# Different behavior of unset vs. empty LESS environment variable?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, git, less

I wanted to change the default behavior of the `less` command, so I added the following to `~/.profile`:

```
LESS="$LESS -x4"
export LESS
```

However, the mere presence of a set `LESS` environment variable seems to change the behavior of the `less` command, since this now causes `git diff` to show me raw escape sequences.

More generally, the output of

```
LESS='' git diff
```

and

```
unset LESS; git diff
```

differs. What is the difference between having `LESS` unset and `LESS` set to an empty value (besides the former apparently implying `-R`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `less`, and everything to do with `git`. Quoting from the [`git-config(1)` manpage](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corepager) (emphasis mine):

> When the `LESS` environment variable is **unset**, Git sets it to `FRX` (if `LESS` environment variable is **set**, Git does not change it at all).

The `R` option of `less` is that which controls whether it interprets colors escapes and such, and which is NOT on by default, but is only set by `git` if the `LESS` environment variable was unset.

Comment: Aha! Thanks, I suspected it was something else interpreting the environment variable, but couldn’t find the right place to look.

Answer (score -3):

`$LESS` is an environment variable used by `less`. From `man less`:

```
Options are also taken from the environment variable "LESS".  For example, to avoid typing
   "less -options ..." each time less is invoked, you might tell csh:

   setenv LESS "-options"

   or if you use sh:

   LESS="-options"; export LESS
```

You should use some other environment variable name.

Comment: Yes, the OP seems to know this. The weird thing is that empty `$LESS` and _unset_ `$LESS` don't behave the same way. The question isn't asking what `$LESS` is  but why `less` seems to display different behavior when the variable is set to empty vs when it is unset.

Comment: `apt-get source less` and start reading.